# HTTP with basic auth Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was trying to recreate the Microsoft BOT Stocks app that was featured on Build 2016, but are unable to successfully test the bot in the emulator.

The emulator gives me this error:

> You are using HTTP with basic auth, which is not a secure way to pass credentials. If you want to use an unsecured HTTP endpoint then
>   you should disable basic authentication.

But how do I do this? I would just like to test my app without HTTPS and that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to test your bot without using HTTPS and just simple layer no security; you could simply go into your primary controller (like MessagesController.cs) and delete/comment out the line that says:

```
[BotAuthentication]
```

You will no longer require HTTPS.